# [cakephp][l10n] merge language file (.po) in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, localization

i am using cakephp 1.2, i have 2 language file, english and chinese, english is default language. i have a problem here, if the message id not exist in chinese language, it will display out the message id. Is it possible i get from default language if message id not exist in the current language po file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common paradigm is to use the default language as the language file keys like:

```
<h2>__('Posts')</h2>
```

Where the English language file may not define any translations, and the Chinese could define them all, or none. If the system doesn't find a matching key in the current language po file, it will simply use the key passed to the `__()` method. So in the above case, if no language file had a `Posts` key then it would simply output `Posts`.